# How can I use setTimeout() so that the letters appear without a delay?

Tags: javascript, arrays, settimeout

I need to have each of these letters appear one after the other in a cascade, just like in an old video game. I have each letter saved in an array, and the function writeText can put all of them in the dialogue box. This works, but I would like to have each letter appear after a very short delay. How can I use timeout to delay them?

```
const phrase1 = ['H', 'i', ',', ' ', 'J', 'o', 'n', 'a', 't', 'h', 'a', 'n'];
function writeText(phrase){
    var dialogue= phrase[0];
    for (i=1; i < phrase.length; i++){
    dialogue= dialogue+ phrase[i];
    document.getElementById("dbox").innerHTML = dialogue; 
};
writeText(phrase1);
```

Comment: Just wrap your line beginning `dialogue=` in a timeout? Try it!

Answer (score 2):

The `writeText()` function should call `setTimeout()` if there are more letters. The timeout should render the letter, and call `writeText()` with the new phrase array by using `Array.slice()` and removing the first item:

```js
const phrase1 = ['H', 'i', ',', ' ', 'J', 'o', 'n', 'a', 't', 'h', 'a', 'n'];

const dbx = document.getElementById("dbox");

function writeText(phrase) {
  if (phrase.length === 0) return;

  setTimeout(() => {
    dbox.innerHTML += phrase[0];
    writeText(phrase.slice(1));
  }, 200);
}

writeText(phrase1);
```

```html
<div id="dbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your function `async` and `await` a dummy `Promise`:

```js
async function writeText(phrase){
    // your code here

    const delayMs = 500; // set this to whatever you like
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayMs));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, I prefer to use a string instead of array. It's easier to replicate and write more phrases easily and faster.

You need to use setTimeout to call the function every X ms, each 'tick' will write 1 letter

```js
const phrase1 = 'Hi, Jonathan!';
const delay = 200 //lower means faster

function writeText(phrase, container){
    var div = document.getElementById(container);
    
    function writeTextHelper (phraseHelper, i) {
      if (phraseHelper.length <= i) { return; }
      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML+''+phraseHelper.charAt(i);
      i++
      setTimeout(_ => { writeTextHelper(phrase, i) }, delay)
    }
    
    setTimeout(_ => { writeTextHelper(phrase, 0) }, delay)
};
writeText(phrase1, 'dbox');
```

```html
<div id='dbox'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit large solution but it may help you.

Here I return the delayed character with a promise resolve and read it by using `async/await`.

```js
const phrase1 = ['H', 'i', ',', ' ', 'J', 'o', 'n', 'a', 't', 'h', 'a', 'n'];

const dbox = document.getElementById('dbox');

const getChar = (char) => {
    let timeout;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout); // Don't forget to clear timeout
 timeout = setTimeout(() => {
     resolve(char);
 }, 150);
    })
}

const writeText = async (arr) => {
    const {length} = arr;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
 let text = await getChar(arr[i]);
 dbox.innerHTML += text;
    }
}

writeText(phrase1);
```

```html
<div id="dbox"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

what you are trying to code is called typewriter it's and it's easy to implement
just check out this code by W3schools
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp

Comment: Thanks @Ali, I didn't know about the txt.charAt, a lot easier than having to type every bit into an array :D

Comment: I did that, and it worked fine for one variable. However, if I need to update the variable, so I put in a while loop.
```
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Hi, Jonathan';
var speed = 50;
var nextDelay= 0;
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    nextDelay = 0
    document.getElementById("dbox").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  } else {
    nextDelay = 1;
  }
};

typeWriter();
while (nextDelay=0){
    console.log ("waiting");
};
console.log ("it worked!");
```

Comment: Why doesn't the while loop make it stop? In my mind, the code runs the typewriter function until evrything in text is written out, then the else condition fires, switches the next delay to 1, then let's the program run on, however, when I tried it, it skipped straight over the while and then turned and displayed the last message without displaying the waiting message once, and then when i switched the while statment from 0 to 1, it started an infinite loop. The only reason I can think of was that the else was firing early, but why is that?

Comment: I hope this is mentioning your name

Comment: this code doesn't work for me! but I think you should check your conditions like < or <= and use for loop instead